# what is (or where can i find) v-if's element-reusing criteria? Using Vue@2.7.14

Tags: vue.js

while Vue's documentation is clear on how you can [prevent an element from being reused](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key) when switching from two branches of a v-if/v-else statement i haven't been able to find the criteria by which two elements are deemed "the same" and therefore reused.
Must they have the same relative position from the parent?
What if they have different positions but the same id?

Querying the repo for "v-if" (as i'm afraid i don't know where to look exactly, excuse my lack of experience) resulted in more than 248 hits.
even a pointer to the source code would suffice, but a direct explanation is very welcome.

Comment: Both should be sibling elements or components then only `v-if`/`else` together will work.

Comment: I don't understand.. I know that v-else must be the next sibling of its v-if, but what elements of that v-if will the v-else "borrow" to save on rendering time?

Comment: `v-if` recreates a DOM element every time when it's value is true. If you don't want to recreate, You should go with `v-show`/`v-hide` directive.